# How to make Avatars Positions Stable in (Unity3D,Vuforia) AR World

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

i am building an AR App that loads 3d FBX Animated avatars dynamically into the scene, and i am facing the current issue :
when i move the toward the avatar, the avatar move forward with the camera, i don't know why is that happening

does anyone has the solution to this problem ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing anything from your project, but did you make sure that your FBX Objects are children of your GroundPlane or ImageTarget?

Comment: Yeah Actually i Created A ground Plane object in the scene , and once i click the avatar icon , i load the avatar to the scene and make the avatar transform as a child to the GroundPlane Object

Comment: the Ground Palne Object has an <Anchor Behavior> .and Plane Trackable Behavior scripts, do i need to make anything else ?

Comment: actually i am loading the FBX files using Trilib library at the run time \

Comment: Do you have any screenshots to explain it better and maybe some code?